# Does anyone know this short Post Apocalyptic Job Interview video? What was it called?

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

This is a short video I saw on Youtube a few years ago. Upbeat.

Man who thinks he is the only person left on earth hears radio announcer offering a receptionist job. Walks across America to apply, giving birds a wide berth, suggesting that everyone died of a bird flu epidemic. Sees no one alive. Arrives, applies to station manager for receptionist job (receptionist is clearly dead) and is told his application will be kept on file. Station manager dies. Man takes over radio station and begins announcing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3--kfthTitI - Not this, but funny

Comment: Low stress environment. Advancement opportunities. Limited time offer.

Comment: This so reminds me of David Brin's "The Postman".  Not at all the same story though.  Postman, not radio announcer.....